# How to build a simple chart in React based on data from API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, d3.js, response

I would like to build a simple chart in React using Nivo library to represent percentage values from data in API response.

The data from the response looks like this: https://run.mocky.io/v3/7c46c4ce-09c0-4f95-b4e1-84ae10bd24ab

I need to represent this data in a really simple line chart.

[image: Here is the simple design]

So far I have this code in my component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import Loader from '../Components/Loader';
import { Bar } from "@nivo/bar";


function ArtistDetail() {
const {artist_uuid} = useParams()
const url = `https://run.mocky.io/v3/${artist_uuid}`; 
const [artist, setArtist] = useState({
    loading: false,
    data: null,
    error: false
})

let content = null;

useEffect(() => {
    setArtist({
      loading: true,
      data: null,
      error: false  
    })
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            setArtist({
                loading: false,
                data: response.data,
                error: false
            })
        })
        .catch(() => {
            setArtist({
                loading: false,
                data: null,
                error: true
            })
        })
}, [url])


if(artist.error) {
    content = <p>There was an error loading an artist.</p>
}


if(artist.loading) {
    content = <p><Loader/></p>
}


if(artist.data) {
    content = 
    <main className="main">
        <section className="section section-artist-detail trending claimed">
            <div className="page">          
                <div className="col visual">
                    <figure>
                        <img src= {artist.data.data.image}/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <button className="btn btn-claim-music-id">Claim music_id</button>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div className="col-wrapper">
                    <div className="col info">
                        <div className="col-content">                               
                            <div className="info-wrapper">
                                <div className="title-wrapper">
                                    <button className="btn btn-solid border btn-booking-request">Booking Request</button>
                                    <h1 className="title">
                                        {artist.data.data.name}
                                        <div className="tooltip-wrapper">
                                            <span className="profile-claimed">Profile claimed</span>
                                            <div className="tooltip">
                                                <h3>Vote for subgenres</h3>
                                                <p>Don’t agree with the subgenres? Add the ones you think are missing or vote for existing to get yours on top!</p>
                                                <div className="stats-sheet">
                                                        {artist.data.data.subgenres.map(subgenre => {
                                                        const {name, score} = subgenre;
                                                        return (
                                                        <div className="row" key={name, score}>
                                                            <h5>{name}</h5>
                                                            <div className="graph-line">
                                                            <span className="line" style= {{width: score + '%'}}>{score}%</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        );
                                                    })}
                                                </div>
                                                <p>
                                                    <button className="btn btn-shadow">Vote now</button>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                          
                                        <span className="trending-icon">Trending</span>
                                    </h1>
                                </div>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <button className="btn btn-save long">Follow</button>
                                    <button className="btn btn-share">
                                        Share
                                        <span>Link copied to clipboard</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <label>Origin</label>
                                    <a className="btn btn-filter-tag">{artist.data.data.country.name}</a>
                                </div>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <label>Genre</label>
                                    <span className="btn btn-filter-tag">{artist.data.data.genre.name}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <label>Subgenres</label>
                                    {artist.data.data.subgenres.map(subgenre => {
                                        const {name} = subgenre;
                                        return (
                                            <span key={name} className="btn btn-filter-tag">{name}</span>                                                           
                                        );
                                    })}
                                    <div className="tooltip-wrapper">
                                        <button className="btn btn-add">Add subgenre</button>
                                        <div className="tooltip">
                                            <h3>Vote for subgenres</h3>
                                            <p>Don’t agree with the subgenres? Add the ones you think are missing or vote for existing to get yours on top!</p>
                                            <div className="stats-sheet">
                                                {artist.data.data.subgenres.map(subgenre => {
                                                        const {name, score} = subgenre;
                                                        return (
                                                        <div className="row" key={name, score}>
                                                            <h5>{name}</h5>
                                                            <div className="graph-line">
                                                                <span className="line" style= {{width: score + '%'}}>{score}%</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        );
                                                    })}
                                            </div>
                                            <p>
                                                <button className="btn btn-shadow">Vote now</button>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="footer-detail">

                                <ul className="social-list">
                                    {artist.data.data.social_links.map(item => {
                                        const {channel, link} = item;
                                        return (
                                            <li key={channel, link}>
                                                <a href= {link} className= {`btn social-icon ${channel}`}>{channel}</a>
                                            </li>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </ul>

                                <div className="tooltip-wrapper">
                                        <button className="btn btn-add">Add links</button>
                                        <div className="tooltip">
                                            <h3>Got more info?</h3>
                                            <p>Add Place's links so everyone can see their social media highlights.</p>
                                            <p>
                                                <button className="btn btn-shadow">Add links</button>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col stats">
                        <div className="col-content">

                        <Bar
                            width={600}
                            height={400}
                            margin={{ top: 60, right: 80, bottom: 60, left: 80 }}
                            data={artist.data.data.popularity}
                            indexBy="city"
                            keys={["percentage"]}
                            labelTextColor="inherit:darker(1.4)"
                            enableGridX={false}
                            layout="horizontal"
                            maxValue={10}
                            axisTop={null}
                            axisRight={null}
                            axisBottom={null}
                            axisLeft={null}
                            enableGridX={false}
                            enableGridY={false}
                            isInteractive={false}
                        />

                            <div className="stats-sheet">
                                <label>Most popular in</label>
                                {artist.data.data.popularity.map(popular => {
                                    const {city} = popular;
                                    return (
                                        <div className="row" key={city}>
                                            <h5>{city}</h5>
                                            <div className="graph-line">
                                                <span className="line" style={{width: 47 + '%'}}>47%</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-scroll-down">Scroll down</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>      
}


return (
    <div>
        {content}
    </div>
)
}


 export default ArtistDetail;
```

I have no idea how to display the percentage data inside this div:

```
<div className="graph-line">
  <span className="line" style={{ width: 47 + "%" }}>
    47%
  </span>
</div>;
```

It looks like this

[image: rendered on the page]

For the chart I used the code from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/p3pv1n4n60?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Good work!

Based on Nivo documentation, I'd try with this

```
 <ResponsiveBar
        data={data.popularity}
        keys={[ 'city', 'percentage' ]}
        maxValue={100}
       ...
   >
```

..setting maxValue in  or  to 100 for percentages. Passing *data.popularity* or *artist.data.data.popularity* to data attribute and setting up appropriate keys.

```
{artist.data.data.popularity.map(popular => {
                                    const {city} = popular;
```

Here might be the problem - destructure both 'city' and 'percentage' from 'popular'.

```
const { city, percentage } = popular
```

then

```
<span>{percentage}%</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the design instead of Nivo you can actually use `simple css` .Below is the code in which I have used `flex` to achieve that.
[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-water-b2f5q)

```js
 <div className="App">
      <h1>Most Popular in</h1>
      {popularity.map((popular) => (
        <div>
          <div>{popular.city}</div>
          <div className="linear-graph">
            <div
              style={{
                background: "black",
                flex: popular.percentage
              }}
            />
            <div
              style={{
                background: "#c5c5c56b",
                flex: 10 - popular.percentage
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

and the css for that

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.linear-graph {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Cheers